# About Google Play Application auto update

Tags: android

So I've made this little app, and shared it among friends. It's on google store.

I've updated newer version of an app today (replaced APK and those little chors I had to do with it). Will my friends recieve my newer version? They still havent.

Did I skip any step? Do I need to somehow initiate the update beside updating apk?

Answer (score 0):

If your friends have the old version of the app installed form the Google Play store, they will get the update of your app after you publish the update of your app properly in the play store.

It generally requires around an hour for the app to get published after you upload the apk to the play store.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to do anything, other then just to increase the version number and code and signing the app with same key store. Google play services will manage everything after that.
2. Some people turn on option update apps only on wifi.
3. It may take some time to publish new version on google play.

**So,if you did as above**, i would suggest you to wait and watch. or visit the play store and check the current version.

Comment: Tnx for the answer. Yes I incremented version2  1.1, version3 1.2 etc